# This discord bot that greets people when they join my server won't work?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to make a welcoming message to whoever joins my discord server with this bot, but nothing happens when someone joins. I am getting an error:

> ReferenceError: channelname is not defined
>     at C:\Users\Vir\Desktop\DiscBot\index.js:13:71
>     at Map.find (C:\Users\Vir\Desktop\DiscBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\Collection.js:506:11)
>     at Client. (C:\Users\Vir\Desktop\DiscBot\index.js:13:43)
>     at Client.emit (events.js:223:5)
>     at Guild._addMember (C:\Users\Vir\Desktop\DiscBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Guild.js:1298:19)
>     at GuildMemberAddHandler.handle (C:\Users\Vir\Desktop\DiscBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\GuildMemberAdd.js:12:13)
>     at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\Vir\Desktop\DiscBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
>     at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\Vir\Desktop\DiscBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
>     at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\Vir\Desktop\DiscBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
>     at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Vir\Desktop\DiscBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
> PS C:\Users\Vir\Desktop\DiscBot>

But I have no clue what that means. I've tried searching it up and found nothing.

The code is

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = "NzEzMTcwNjc4NjYwMjAyNTA2.XscOxQ.0YxwpbBEITN0DIwGFwYIdRxCOu0";

const PREFIX = ";";

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('This bot is online!');
})

bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member =>{
    const channel = member.guild.channels.find(channel => channelname === "welcome");
    if(!channel) return;

    channel.send('Welcome, ${member}, make sure to read the rules and verfiy.') 
});


bot.on('message', message=>{

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ")

    switch(args[0]){
        case 'Version':
            message.reply('Version 1.0.0');
        break;
        case 'Commands':
            message.reply(';Version ;Commands');
        break;
        
        
    }
})

bot.login(token);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that i use for this

```
      client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {

    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL_ID'); 
    channel.send(`**Hey ${member.user}, welcome to the server!\nMake sure to read the rules in <#CHANNEL_ID>**`); 
});
```

Comment: You can add more explanation to the code, what it does and how it does.

Answer (score 0):

They have changed it, so you'll need to use `cache` now. So in this case:

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member =>{
    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "welcome");
    if(!channel) return;

    channel.send('Welcome, ${member}, make sure to read the rules and verfiy.') 
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried that and get ypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Vir\Desktop\DiscBot\index.js:13:49)
    at Client.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Guild._addMember (C:\Users\Vir\Desktop\DiscBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Guild.js:1298:19)
    at GuildMemberAddHandler.handle

Comment: Which version of discord.js are you using? (by the way, just make sure its channel.name and not channelname)

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that `channelname` is not defined. I believe you should be using `channel.name` instead, just a simple typo.

Following OP's comment, I checked the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=cache) and you must access the `cache` property to get a list of channels, like so:

```js
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "welcome");

    if(!channel) {
        return;
    }

    channel.send(`Welcome, ${member}, make sure to read the rules and verfiy.`) 
});
```

Comment: I'm getting error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Vir\Desktop\DiscBot\index.js:13:49)
    at Client.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Guild._addMember (C:\Users\Vir\Desktop\DiscBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Guild.js:1298:19)
    at GuildMemberAddHandler.handle (C:\Users\Vir\Desktop\DiscBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\GuildMemberAdd.js:12:13)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a fix for this error.